# How to get toplists of multiple columns

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, rlang

I can select and arrange a single column:

```
iris %>%
  select(Petal.Width, Species) %>%
  arrange(desc(Petal.Width))
```

But I want to do this for the whole dataframe. I'm approaching this with a forloop:

```
features <- colnames(iris)
top <- data.frame()
for (i in 1:length(features)) {
  label <- features[[i]]
  iris %>%
    select(label, Species) %>%
    arrange(desc(label)) %>%
    top_n(3) %>%
    rbind(top)
}
# Error in arrange_impl(.data, dots) : 
# incorrect size (1) at position 1, expecting : 150
```

Which gives me an error.

Apparently the `arrange(desc(label))` doesn't work. I searched around and tried things like `UQ` and `substitute` to unquote the `label`, but with no result.

The `rbind(top)` and the `top_n` end might also be not exactly what I want, but the main problem I have now is how to use the `label` so the forloop wil accept it.

And maybe someone knows a better approach alltogether than my forloop...

The desired output is a dataframe, with the top 3 of every column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use something on all columns, there are multiple ways. I like to `gather` (or melt) the data first and then use dplyr again.

For example, in your case, this would result in

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

iris %>% 
  gather("var", "val", -Species) %>%
  group_by(var) %>% 
  arrange(desc(val)) %>% 
  top_n(3)
#> Selecting by val
#> # A tibble: 14 x 3
#> # Groups:   var [4]
#>      Species          var   val
#>       <fctr>        <chr> <dbl>
#>  1 virginica Sepal.Length   7.9
#>  2 virginica Sepal.Length   7.7
#>  3 virginica Sepal.Length   7.7
#>  4 virginica Sepal.Length   7.7
#>  5 virginica Sepal.Length   7.7
#>  6 virginica Petal.Length   6.9
#>  7 virginica Petal.Length   6.7
#>  8 virginica Petal.Length   6.7
#>  9    setosa  Sepal.Width   4.4
#> 10    setosa  Sepal.Width   4.2
#> 11    setosa  Sepal.Width   4.1
#> 12 virginica  Petal.Width   2.5
#> 13 virginica  Petal.Width   2.5
#> 14 virginica  Petal.Width   2.5
```

What you see is that `top_n` selects the top-n values not top-n entries, but you can substitute the function for `slice(1:3)`

Does that give you what you where looking for?

Comment: Great answer. Minor addition: if using `slice(1:3)` to select the top 3 entries in each group, the result can be further passed through `spread` to get the data.frame back into the original wide format.

Comment: Glad you like it. To spread the values again, we would have to carry some kind of identifier, otherwise spread will stop as we have duplicate identifiers... But otherwise you are correct.